# Multithreaded access to the data in a tree

Tags: c, multithreading, data-structures, thread-safety, binary-search-tree

I want to create binary search tree data structure in C/C++ where each node holds some data (objects or pointers). I will access this tree in multi-threading environment, If I can guarantee that each thread will access (read) different subtrees/paths/nodes of the tree, than it is thread-safe to modify objects (or data pointers point to) stored in nodes and so I can avoid locking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locking is not the *goal*, providing exclusive access to a resources is. Locking is a *means* of achieving that goal. You've stated you can achieve that goal by some other means. Using this other means would be as thread-safe as using locks would be.